# How to Resize the Custom Post Images?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, images

am Having Custom Field named as thumb.i want to show the images using these custom fields.i want to be fix the image size.

My code is

```
 <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

i tried timthumb also like this

```
 <img class="thumb" timthumb.php?src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>"&q=100 alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

any one help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using the inbuilt [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails), which were introduced in WordPress 2.9 - these are easier to use than custom fields and have things like sizing built in.

Once you've enabled Post Thumbnails, you can set their default size using [set_post_thumbnail_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) and then use them in your theme with **the_post_thumbnail**

Comment: you are right @:tallphil,am familiar in that.Here i want to take the images from outside of my website.so only i used custom field.here post thumbnails is not working.i gave the direct link of the images in my custom field.thanks for your try...

Comment: ok, in that case timthumb is probably your best bet. You had some errors in the HTML markup posted above, I've described them in a separate answer below...

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the second (timthumb) code. The src= was after the tumthumb.php instead of before, plus the " should be after the &q=100. It should be:

```
<img class="thumb" src="timthumb.php?<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```